# How can I specify line-length behaviour in Apache FOP?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, ecrion

[image: Output from Ecrion and Apache FOP]

I have rendered the same XSL-FO in a trial of Ecrion and Apache FOP, and you'll notice that the two renderers have produced different line-lengths on lines 2 and 3.  The way Ecrion has rendered the text is the way I would like Apache FOP to do it.

Is there an attribute I can add to the `<fo:block>` containing the text that would cause FOP to render the text with the same line length as Ecrion?  Is there a command-line switch I can pass to FOP to obtain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, there is only a single implementation of a line breaking algorithm present.

In LineLayoutManager.java there's a private method called "findOptimalBreakingPoints".  Around line 834-ish I commented-out the lines that increment "maxAdjustment" and the "balancing" of the lines no longer occurs.

I'm aware this is a hacky solution, but I didn't have the time to investigate further and write my own line breaking algorithm.